# How to find max duplicate number count in given array using for loop

Tags: java

input: `arr[]={4,3,6,6,4,8,1,9,3,6,7,8,6}`
output: `6-count (4)`

```
public static int countmaxDuplicate(int arr[]) {
        int maxcount = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > maxcount) {
                    count = maxcount;
                }
            }
        }

        return maxcount;
    }
```

this code i am trying to implement to get max duplicate count but not able to get solution please suggest me how get output  using for loop

Comment: j<arr.length-1 , i think this might be the problem

Comment: It should be j<arr.length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few issues in your code

```
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

        }
```

And

```
        if (count > maxcount) {
                maxcount = count;
        }
```

Plus, you need to reinitialise `count` in every stage.

Full version:

```
public static int countmaxDuplicate(int arr[]) {
    int maxcount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
            }

        }
        maxcount = Integer.max(maxcount, count);
    }

    return maxcount;
}
```

You can also add a boolean array `check` to avoid duplicating work

```
public static int countmaxDuplicate(int arr[]) {
    int maxcount = 0;
    boolean[]check = new boolean[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if(check[i]){
           continue;
        }
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                check[j] = true;
                count++;
            }

        }
        maxcount = Integer.max(maxcount, count);
    }

    return maxcount;
}
```

Or even consider to use a HahsMap so this will have O(n) time complexity

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap();
for(int i : arr){
   count.put(i, count.getOrDefault(count, 0) + 1);
}

int maxCount;
for(int i : count.values()){
   maxCount = Integer.max(maxCount, i);
}
return maxCount;
```

Comment: What do you mean by return count and no need of maxcount

Comment: @MaxVollmer you just have spoken my words

Comment: @MaxVollmer fixed

Answer (score 2):

In inner for loop, you are not inspecting last element every time. So change the for loop as:

```
 for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length ; j++) {
    //your logic
 }
```

Also other mistakes are you've to initialize count to 1 initially and also you need to reset count. Also your assignment is not right. You are maintaining `maxcount` as your final answer, so you need to update it instead of `count`. So following will work perfectly.

```
public static int countmaxDuplicate(int arr[]) {
    int maxcount = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
            }

        }
        if (count > maxcount) {
                 maxcount= count;
        }
    }

    return maxcount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just gonna post it here, I don't like `for` loops.

```java
int[] arr = {4, 3, 6, 6, 4, 8, 1, 9, 3, 6, 7, 8, 6};

Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()
        ));

Map.Entry<Integer, Long> max = Collections.max(
        map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()
);

System.out.println(max.getKey());
```

First you group them all by their count (maybe you need more than element with max count in the future? who knows), then you select max entry and print the key from that.

Comment: "_I don't like `for` loops._" Why ? You replace all your loops with `stream` ? I hope not ;)

Comment: The last line of the question states: `suggest me how get output using for loop`. What if OP uses Java version < 8? You should respect the OP's requirement over your preferences. Moreover, the [tag:java-stream] is not a magic bullet.

Comment: @Nikolas That's why I didn't say anything like `This is the only right way, ignore other answers`. Maybe someone has similar problem and wants other perspective. I had that situation many times when someone posted a solution and I used something from the bottom of the page, because I liked it more.

Comment: @AxelH When it's possible and it looks better to me then yes. If I worked in time-sensitive systems or something then I would think twice before doing it, but readability is more important to me.